# How can one calculate ROC's AUCs in complex designs with clustering in R?

Tags: r, survey, roc, auc

The packages that calculate AUCs I've found so far do not contemplate sample clustering, which increases standard errors compared to simple random sampling. I wonder if the ones provided by these packages could be recalculated to allow for clustering.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably replicate weights, as long as you can get point estimates of AUC that incorporate weights.

If you convert your design into a replicate-weights design object (using `survey::as.svrepdesign()`), you can then run any R function or expression using the replicate weights using `survey::withReplicates()` and return a standard error.